# ssh connection when building in Jenkins (Host key verification failed.)

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

Created an item in Jenkins that should execute a bash script connecting to a VM:

```
ssh user@192.168.100.100 'ls'
```

When executing, I get an error:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

At the same time, I added the ssh key to Manage Credentials / Global credentials, specifying the key, id and username

The key itself was generated on the machine 192.168.100.100 using ssh-keygen and used id_rsa

But I could not defeat the mistake, tell me where to look

If you run the same command in the console, I get a response after entering the password

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [SSH Step plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) instead. Which will give you more control over the connection. The syntax will look something like the below.

```
    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'test'
    remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
    remote.user = 'root'
    remote.password = 'password'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
    }
```